# Why does Ubuntu Desktop LTS 20.04 creates an UEFI boot partition in UEFI legacy (MBR) mode?

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi, ubiquity

I have installed Ubuntu Desktop LTS 20.04 64 bit via USB-Flash and selected the options...

- Erase disk
- Advanced feature... > Use LVM > Encrypt for security

As shown in this picture:

[image: Ubuntu Desktop Installation type step]

[ubiquity source](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/20.04.15.19)

[Ubuntu 20.04 release reference](https://releases.ubuntu.com/focal/)

Because of UEFI firmware was set in BIOS compatibility mode, the installation used a standard MBR partition table with GRUB 2 as MBR boot code:

```bash
# sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disklabel type: dos # dos => MBR
Device     Boot   Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   1050623   1048576   512M  b W95 FAT32
/dev/sda2       1052670 488396799 487344130 232,4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1052672   4050943   2998272   1,4G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       4052992 488396799 484343808   231G 83 Linux

# hexdump -v -s 0x80 -n 2 -e '2/1 "%x" "\n"' /dev/sda
020 # This identifies the MBR boot code as GRUB 2, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/702790/160124

# sudo lsblk
sda                     8:0    0 232,9G  0 disk  
├─sda1                  8:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                  8:2    0     1K  0 part  
├─sda5                  8:5    0   1,4G  0 part  /boot
└─sda6                  8:6    0   231G  0 part  
  └─sda6_crypt        253:0    0   231G  0 crypt 
    ├─vgubuntu-root   253:1    0   230G  0 lvm   /
    └─vgubuntu-swap_1 253:2    0   980M  0 lvm   [SWAP]

# sudo ls -a /boot/efi
.  ..

# sudo df | grep "Filesystem\|/dev/sda1"
Filesystem                1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                    523248        4    523244   1% /boot/efi

# fsck.fat -v -n /dev/sda1
Boot sector contents:
System ID "mkfs.fat"
Media byte 0xf8 (hard disk)
       512 bytes per logical sector
      4096 bytes per cluster
        32 reserved sectors
/dev/sda1: 0 files, 1/130812 clusters # No files, one cluster used for FAT root directory.
```

As you can see `/boot/efi` is empty (4K used is the FAT root directory, see https://superuser.com/a/1727654/505763).

## So, why did Ubuntu created a `/boot/efi` partition?

Comment: You probably would have to file bug report and see if any developer explains why. Only recently noticed that with some BIOS installs. Most installs now are UEFI. Ubuntu works better with newer systems that are UEFI.  And even with a BIOS install, better to use gpt partitioning, if not installing Windows in old BIOS mode on same drive. I used Ubuntu on gpt drive with BIOS starting in 2010. GPT Advantages (older 2010 but still valid)  see post#2 by srs5694:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1457901 & 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Partitioning#Choosing_between_GPT_and_MBR

Comment: @oldfred Yeah i know that i should have used UEFI, i didn't check the UEFI mode before installation. BUT THANK YOU for comfirming this. Did you notice the same for Ubuntu 22 LTS installs or only Ubuntu 20? I already asked in the Ubuntu chat but nobody seems to know why. Just wanted to make sure this is not by purpose.

Comment: Not sure when it changed. Just have not seen a lot of BIOS installs with full Ubuntu. Those with 10 year old systems, normally use one of the lighter weight flavors and some of those use a different installer. Ubuntu also lets you use MBR with UEFI, which I think it should not. So you could convert to UEFI, just by reinstalling grub in UEFI mode. Now have to check fstab to see if ESP is mounted to know if current install is UEFI. Or: `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD" `If good backups: http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/mbr2gpt.html & reinstall grub.

Comment: @oldfred Converting to UEFI is definitely planned, thanks!